# Constructor calls for subclasses

Tags: java, constructor

Consider the constructor of a subclass. What happens during its execution if this constructor does not have a call of the constructor of its superclass as the first statement.

My answer (want to verify that it is correct):

If the Subclass does not call the constructor from the Superclass then the default constructor from the Superclass will be used. If there is no default constructor then the code will fail to compile.

Comment: An easy way to test if you have the right answer is to do some quick java code and see if it performs like you think it will.

Comment: Can you change your title to relate to the contents of your question, please.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: That's not always a good way of finding the right answer - because some behaviour may be implementation specific or "not guaranteed" in other ways.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would use the term "parameterless constructor" rather than "default constructor" and I'd also add that the code will fail to compile if there's a parameterless constructor but it's inaccessible - but otherwise that's correct.

I would probably express the answer in terms of a constructor with no explicit chaining to either a superclass constructor or another constructor in the same class as being equivalent to one which calls

```
super();
```

at the start. I'd also refer to the [Java Language Specification section 8.8.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body is implicitly assumed by the compiler to begin with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.